# Normalize numbers in an object

Tags: javascript, object, numbers, normalize

What's the best way to normalize numbers (to range 0-1 or 0-100) in an object.

Eg:

```
obj = {
   "key1": 100,
   "key2": 500,
   "key3": 1000
}
```

Desired result-

```
obj = {
   "key1": 0.1,
   "key2": 0.5,
   "key3": 1
}
```

I can normalize numbers in an array with-

```
ratio = Math.max.apply(Math, numbers) / 100;

numbers = numbers.map(function (v) {
  return Math.round(v / ratio);
});
```

But what's the best way to normalize if the numbers are in an objecT?

Comment: How hard would it actually be to try something?

Comment: the range 0 ... 1 does not fit with your wanted results.

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly easy to do - loop through your object and transform the range, here's some pseudo code:

```
  var applyToRange = function (num, source, destination) {
            if (num < source[0] || num > source[1]) {
                return NaN;
            }
            var oldMinValue = source[0];
            var oldMaxValue = source[1];
            var newMinValue = destination[0];
            var newMaxValue = destination[1];
            var a = (oldMaxValue - oldMinValue);
            var b = (newMaxValue - newMinValue);

            return ((num - oldMinValue) / a) * b + newMinValue;

        }

      for (var key in obj) {
          if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) { 
           // applyToRange();
          }
       }
```

You will need to know the min and max values in your object to make this particular method work.

Answer (score 0):

If lodash (3.10 which is current) is an option, this can be written in a very concise way:

```
var obj = {
  "key1": 100,
  "key2": 500,
  "key3": 1000
}

var max = Math.max.apply(Math, _.values(obj))

obj = _.mapValues(obj, function(val) {
  return val / max;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This script moves the given values in this interval [100, 1000] to the wanted interval of [0, 1]. The base of the calculation is the slope `m` and some correction values.

```js
var obj = {
        "key1": 100,
        "key2": 500,
        "key3": 1000
    },
    range = [0, 1],
    i,
    min, max,
    m,
    values = [];
for (i in obj) {
    values.push(obj[i]);
    obj[i] = { value: obj[i] };
}
min = Math.min.apply(Math, values);
max = Math.max.apply(Math, values);
m = (range[1] - range[0]) / (max - min);
for (i in obj) {
    obj[i].normalized = (obj[i].value - min) * m + range[0];
}
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score -1):

How about?

```
obj = {
   "key1": 100,
   "key2": 500,
   "key3": 1000
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4));

for (var p in obj){
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)){
        obj[p] /= 0.42;
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4));
```

> {
>       "key1": 100,
>       "key2": 500,
>       "key3": 1000 } {
>       "key1": 238.0952380952381,
>       "key2": 1190.4761904761906,
>       "key3": 2380.952380952381 }